# React variable value isnt changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i want to change a variable value and than log it to the console from another function.

But when i am logging it its always the same output and not the changed one.

Ive already tried it with the useState hook but that seems to be the same problem.

I want to change the `text` variable when the `handleStart` gets called, and than log it the console when `handleClick` gets called.

But when `handleClick` gets called it always log 'Hello World'

```
const [task, setTask] = useState();


let text = 'Hello World';

const pRef = useRef([]);

  const updateTextArray = () => {
    const buttons = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    return buttons.map((button, index) => (
      <div
        className="grid-item"
        key={index}
        ref={ref => (pRef.current[index] = ref)}
        onClick={() => {
          handleClick(index, game);
        }}
      ></div>
      //Setup the spans with the words
    ));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTask(updateTextArray);
  }, []);



const handleStart = () => {

    text = 'loaded';
     //.....
    
  };

const handleClick = index => {
    console.log(text);
    if (!isStarted) return;
    //.....
  };


 return (
    <div>
        <div className="grid-container">{task}</div>
       
        <div>
          <button onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
        </div>
   
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible version with the code that leads to the issue that you are facing. With the current state we can't tell anything since we don't know how you call those functions

Comment: i added more information to the post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added useState to your code and a button to run your handleClick method and everything looks to be working.

(edited using callbackHook)

[Working example.](https://playcode.io/1470442)

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const [task, setTask] = useState();
  const [text, setText] = useState('Hello World');
  const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState();

  const pRef = useRef([]);

  const updateTextArray = useCallback(() => {
    const buttons = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    return buttons.map((button, index) => (
      <button
        className="grid-item"
        key={index}
        ref={ref => (pRef.current[index] = ref)}
        onClick={() => handleClick(index)}
      >{index}</button>
      //Setup the spans with the words
    ));
  }, [text]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTask(updateTextArray);
  }, [updateTextArray]);

  const handleStart = () => {
    setText('loaded');
  };

  const handleClick = useCallback((index, text) =>{
    console.log(index, text);
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="grid-container">{task}</div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
        <span>{text}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It worked when im clicking on the `click` button, but when im calling the handleClick from the updateTextArray div's, it doesnt work.

Comment: I think the value isn't changing because the function hasn't changed.

You should use useCallbak hook within the functions, with the right dependencies, in order for it to work propperly

Comment: I've just updated the example using useCallback hook and it looks like its woking as expected now.

Comment: Thank you! I have now got it running perfectly